# Angular Test error: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm having the following test error:

> ✖ should create
>         Chrome 81.0.4044 (Mac OS X 10.14.6)
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
>           at AccountsInfoComponent.loadCompanyTypes (webpack:///./src/app/contacts/contact/overview/accounts-info/accounts-info.component.ts?:75:13)
>           at AccountsInfoComponent.initAccountsInfoForm (webpack:///./src/app/contacts/contact/overview/accounts-info/accounts-info.component.ts?:129:14)
>           at AccountsInfoComponent.updateContactAccounts (webpack:///./src/app/contacts/contact/overview/accounts-info/accounts-info.component.ts?:89:22)
>           at AccountsInfoComponent.set [as contact] (webpack:///./src/app/contacts/contact/overview/accounts-info/accounts-info.component.ts?:47:18)
>           at UserContext.eval (webpack:///./src/app/contacts/contact/overview/accounts-info/accounts-info.component.spec.ts?:120:27)

I have a service with this method:

```
getCompanyType(contact_id: string) {
    const url = `api/v1/contact/sponsors_list?contact_id=${contact_id}`
    return this.http.get<any>(url)
  }
```

And a component with this method:

```
loadCompanyTypes() {
    this.editService
      .getCompanyType(this.contact.id)
      .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(classic_where_held => {
        const arrayOfTypes = classic_where_held.where_held_classic_id
        this.companyTypes = arrayOfTypes.map(x => {
          return { classic_id: x[0], name: x[1] }
        })
      })
  }
```

I mocked my service method in the tests:

```
const mockContactEditService = {
    addEditSection: jasmine.createSpy('addEditSection'),
    setSaveUpdateContact: jasmine.createSpy('addEditSection'),
    getCompanyType: jasmine.createSpy('getCompanyType')
  }
```

The tests break here `.pipe(untilDestroyed(this))` it says getCompanyType doesn't return nothing and it should return an Observable???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, I needed change my mock in this way:

```
getCompanyType: jasmine.createSpy('getCompanyType').and.returnValue(of(mockCompanyTypes))
```

This solve the problem!